# My nexus S phone not showing up in Android device choose

Tags: android

1. I can see my own device under "adb devices" and
2. having Run Configuration -> Target -> Deployment Target Selection Mode already set to "Manual" (in fact with my IDE, there's no Manual option, for some reason) and
3. Having my phone set to USB Debugging mode
4. My app is set to android:debuggable=true

However, I am still not able to see my device in "Android Device Chooser". Can anyone help me out in this? I'm using ADT as my IDE. Thanks in advance

Comment: When you connect your device, are you able to see data in the Logcat?

Comment: Yes I can see data in there, updating all the time

Comment: So try this: right click on the project, and run as android application, while your device is connected. It should launch on the device now

Comment: I see "Android Device Chooser" coming up, but still my phone is not coming up

Comment: Is the target API of your application matching the OS of the phone?

Comment: My phone version is Android 4.1.2 and I have installed both API-16 (Android 4.1.2) and API-17 (Android 4.2). Do I need to uninstall API-17 from SDK Manager?

Comment: Is the target API of your application that you are deploying API 17? If so try changing it to 16 and running it

Comment: Thanks, I think that maybe the one, I'll try matching the versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SalGad, it's to do with my API version that's different between my phone and project build target. The version I had on my Nexus S phone is 4.1.2 and the one on my project is 4.2

Answer (score 3):

- Enable USB Debugging in your  cell phone.
- go to Windows´s Device Manager and you can see the failed driver message, Right click and select "Update Driver Software", then "Browse my computer for driver software".
- Browse to your Google Driver location for example "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android_Jorgesys\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver".
- Select "Android Composite ADB Interface" driver and click on Next button, then Install.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it's to do with my API versions

Comment: This worked for us: intern and me searched for an hour, then we found out that OS used some other USB driver instead of the Google USB driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of issues with this myself. I know that this question is already answered, but the selected answer didn't work for me. So instead of asking a new question I'll add in what DID work for me. I enabled dev mode on the phone, I tried setting the drivers - but the only drivers it would take were generic storage (or phone) drivers. For me I had to set to enable dev debugging mode on the phone and then the option appeared in my device manager for the ADB composite device.
Hopefully I save someone else the same trouble I had - just enable the USB Debugging Option.